# Qt5: Poppler weird linker error

Tags: c++, windows, qt, linker-errors, poppler

I downloaded pre-built win32 poppler binaries from [this page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/poppler-win32/). Added the path for the include folder and lib folder in the .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\\test_folder\\poppler-0.24.5-win32\\include\\poppler-qt5"
LIBS += -L/"C:\\test_folder\\poppler-0.24.5-win32\\lib"
```

In main.cpp i include "poppler-qt5.h" without errors, so I would think that poppler was added correctly. However when testing it by opening a pdf file, [as described here](http://people.freedesktop.org/~aacid/docs/qt5/),

```
QString path = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\spool\\PRINTERS\\test_file.pdf";
Poppler::Document *doc = Poppler::Document::load(path);
```

I receive a linker error:

[image: Error message]

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Are you using the MinGW or Microsoft Visual C (MSVC) compiler within QtCreator? (hint: try MinGW)

Answer (score 0):

I am missing the -l in yout LIBS line

```
LIBS += -L/"C:\\test_folder\\poppler-0.24.5-win32\\lib" -lpoppler-qt5
```

Eventually rename the lib since .dll.a is not a standard extension in windows.

Edit: Works without renaming the library:

.pro File:

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$quote(D:\Users\username\Downloads\poppler-0.24.5-win32\poppler-0.24.5-win32\include\poppler-qt5)
LIBS += -L$$quote(D:\Users\username\Downloads\poppler-0.24.5-win32\poppler-0.24.5-win32\lib) -lpoppler-qt5
```

.cpp File:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <mycpp.h>

#include <poppler-qt5.h>

/* Some Code here */
QString path = "D:\\SomePDF.pdf";
Poppler::Document *doc = Poppler::Document::load(path);
/* More Code here */
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. If I add -lpoppler-qt5 i get a linker error: Cannot open file poppler-qt5.lib, which is pretty understable since it's not there.. Changing libpoppler-qt5.dll.a to poppler-qt5.lib does not work either. Is -lpoppler-qt5 necessary?

Comment: It is, but change it to libpoppler-qt5.dll (not sure if this is a dll though, since .dll is shared on windows and .a would be static on linux)

Comment: It works fine for me without renaming, i'll add the code to the post

Comment: Thank you for your work Sebastian. It does still not work, unfortunately. I created a new project and new download, still doesn't work. I am using the MSVC compiler, I will try to see if i can get the MinGW compiler to work as @walkingTarget suggested. Whcih compiler do you use?

Comment: Removed my installation of Qt with MSVC and installed it with MinGW. I get no link errors now, but the program crashes even with the simple sample code you posted above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved it with this method:

Copy dll file if you find in folder \poppler-0.24.5-win32\bin\ to folder where Qt generate executable file. Then download zlib1.dll and insert this dll to folder where Qt generate executable file. Try now. 
This works for me. I compiled with qt 5.3 in Windows XP SP3.